# Need a styled radio button to be composed of two seperate boxes

Tags: html, css

I need the radio button below to be composed of two separate boxes, rather than one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.navText {
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color: white;
}
input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}
.overlay {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
display: table;
background-color: grey;
}
input[type=radio]:hover + .overlay {
background-color: red;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .overlay {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<label><input type="radio" name="nav" onclick="document.location='#';">
<div class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">Home</h1></div></label>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like it to work like this (but still as a radio button):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
width: 153px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
}
.container:hover div {
background-color: red;
}
.box1 {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
margin-right: 3px;
background-color: grey;
}
.box2 {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
background-color: grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the radio button be composed of two separate boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add another box using pseudo-element `:after`

```
.overlay:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    left:104px;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.overlay:hover,
.overlay:hover:after {
    background-color: red;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + .overlay,
input[type=radio]:checked + .overlay:after {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also, if you want the overlay to change color on a :hover, you need to apply the styling to the overlay, not to the radio button (as it's not possible to hover the radio button itself).

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0r1tefr8/2/

Comment: The only problem is I need to be able to add an image to the 'after' box, which I'm not sure I can do with that setup.

Comment: Would you be able to add the image as a CSS background-image?

http://jsfiddle.net/0r1tefr8/3/